# Winform application showing timeout expire error while uploading data into database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an win form application. Where I take Excel file and upload the data into Database.But when i am trying to upload data it is showing error
"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." 
I have changed the connection time out property

But still its showing same error. 
N.B: It works once then again show the problem. My Excel file contain more than 0.5million Data

Comment: How you are importing data, picking rows 1 by 1 from excel and inserting? or is there any bulk copy you are using?

Comment: Yes I am using bulk copy and found the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I am using bulk copy so i just increased the bulkcopy timeout value and it works.

> bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 9999;
>
> bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

I just wrote the Time out code before writing to the server.

Answer (score 5):

Setting connection timeout is not relevant, make sure you have the CommandTimeout property set in your Command object,

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandTimeout = 0; //Wait indefinitely
```

For more information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Uploading large quantity of data(half million, in your case) one record at a time is not recommended. Use SqlBulkCopy as it will be more efficient, read excel file, copy records to a text file and bulk upload, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx